# C++ char* to HEX conversion

Tags: c++, hex, type-conversion

I want to convert byte data (file body) to hex in order to print it. I've copied a function for conversion, but not exactly understand it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

std::string byte_2_str(char* bytes, int size) {
    char const hex[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A',   'B','C','D','E','F'};
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        const char ch = bytes[i];
        str.append(&hex[(ch  & 0xF0) >> 4], 1);
        str.append(&hex[ch & 0xF], 1);
    }

return str;

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char data[] = "1";
    std::string str = byte_2_str(data, sizeof(data));
    std::cout << str << std::endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

What is that shift (4) and mask 0xF for? And how it works? Also, when i'am tried to pass "1" as argument to func, it returns 3100, but i supposed it will return 0100 because 1 is 1 in both dec or hex. Am i wrong?

Comment: That `sizeof(data)` is wrong, because you are essentially including the null-character in you calculations. You should use `strlen(data)`. That being said, you're kind of mixing C strings and C++ strings here.

Comment: i know, i'am using char* because i have a BYTE array of file contents (similar to char) so strlen won't be useful(as there are \r\n characters in array)

Comment: *What is that shift (4) and mask 0xF for?* it moves the result of `(ch  & 0xF0)` from bits 4..7 to bits 0..3, presumably so it's easier to access them

Comment: With `char data[] = "1"`, you have `sizeof(data) == 2` while `strlen(data) == 1`. I believe you need the latter. Does that make it clearer? I am referring to the code that you've posted. "I have a BYTE array of file contents" is not reflected in your question!!!

Comment: if i will ust strlen it won't work with BYTE array beacuse there may be lots of null-terminating symbols.

Comment: As I said, I don't see any "BYTE array" in your question. I see `char data[] = "1"`, and the size of this array is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One digit in the hexadecimal representation corresponds to four bits in the binary representation.

`ch & 0xF0` masks out the high four bits. `>> 4` shifts them into the low bits.

```
0xAB & 0xF0 -> 0xA0
0xA0 >> 4 -> 0xA
```

`ch & 0xF` masks out the low four bits.

```
0xAB & 0xF -> 0xB
```

The reason for your unexpected result is that the character `'1'` is `0x31` (49 in decimal) in the ASCII encoding.
You're looking up the character's numerical representation, not the number it represents.

You'll get the expected results if you do

```
char data[] = {1};
```

Comment: So when HEX-editors working with files it means they editing hex values of ascii codes or i didn't get it?

Comment: @IvanPetrov They usually display the hexadecimal numbers that correspond to the binary data in the file, so if the file happens to contain ASCII-encoded text, they display the hexadecimal representation of the text's ASCII encoding. It's just a binary->hexadecimal mapping, the editor doesn't care what the numbers in the file represent.

Answer (score 1):

Side note:

```
Also, when i'am tried to pass "1" as argument to func, it returns 3100
```

This is correct. The function takes a `char` array, but operates on the array as raw data, not as if it was a set of characters. This is just because C does not have a "byte" type, and because the `char` type is guaranteed to be 8 bits, it's the most convenient type that can be used to represent bytes.

If you look in the ASCII table, '1' corresponds to 0x31. If you use the following, then you'll see the output you expect:

```
char[] data = {1};
```

As the others have said, you then get the 0x00 after it because your existing code is also including the `NULL` terminator.